# Android studio crash every time after installing Sceneform plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, arcore, sceneform

Android studio crash every time it is launched after installing Sceneform plugin.Studio works fine when Sceneform plugin is uninstalled. Is it a version compatible issue ? Couldn't find any logs related to studio crash in the studio log file.

Version Details
Android studio version is 3.1.4. 
Sceneform Plugin Version : 1.4.0.